# Angular resource url always has question mark

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular resource that I want to generate the url below
/api/customerSearch/Search/xxxx

But what I am getting is /api/customerSearch/Search?criteria=xxxx

controller

```
 core.controller('customerSearchCtrl',
 function customerSearchCtrl($scope, customerSearch) {
 $scope.getCustomerSearchResults = function () {
       $scope.customerSearchResults = customerSearch.get(
                        {
                          crtieria: $scope.searchCriteria 
                        });
 }; });
```

Resource

```
 core.factory('customerSearch', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
 return $resource('./api/customerSearch/Search/:criteria/');

}]);
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the parameter specified in the controller doesn't match the route template.

In the controller it's 'crtieria', in the service it's 'criteria'

Edit: To clarify, when angular can't find a match for the property in the route template, the default is to pass all additional parameters as querystring

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the parameter specified in the controller doesn't match the route template.

```
core.controller('customerSearchCtrl',
    function customerSearchCtrl($scope, customerSearch) {
        $scope.getCustomerSearchResults = function() {
            $scope.customerSearchResults = customerSearch.get({
                criteria: $scope.searchCriteria
            });
        };
    });
```

Define the url as follows:

```
core.factory('customerSearch', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('./api/customerSearch/Search/:criteria', { criteria: '@criteria' });
}]);
```

Hope this will help you.